# I want to carry a CD on an international flight is that allowed? And if yes in hand bag or check in bag?

Tags: india, indonesia, mumbai, bali

I am travelling from Bali, Indonesia to Mumbai, India. I want to carry a CD that has a video of  a water sport that I did in Bali. Will there be any problem on Bali airport or Mumbai airport if I put that CD in my hand bag? As in will I be allowed to carry it?  I have a flight after that to Bangalore and need to report to office. So I cannot afford to take the next flight. Please advice.

Comment: Why would you think it wouldn't be allowed?

Comment: @ZachLipton A broken CD would make a wonderful improvised knife. (Along with almost any number of other items - including credit cards)

Comment: If you're female, do you think customs could be unhappy if you're showing too much skin?

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, you can bring CDs with you, either checked in or carried on.

There is a small chance that they will be inspected on arrival by Indian customs, but if the contents are just scuba diving etc, there's nothing to worry about.